# How to configure routing to a controller with mapping @RequestMapping("**/file") using spring gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I have controller with request mapping @RequestMapping("**/file").

I know that I can write something like that

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=file
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8080
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/*/*/file/**
```

but how to write a pattern so that all requests containing /file in their URL can be redirected to my controller, regardless of how many segments there are before /file ?

Answer (score 0):

try the below i am not sure but it should work

as you used `///file/**` but as far as i understand it means there are exactly two segments before `/file` so it wouldn't be suitable for all the cases as the there could be more then two or even less segments befror the `/file` , so try the following change and let me know.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/file/**
```